# Ubuntu 14.04 isn't show remote mount path

Tags: mount

Hi I'm working on setup ubuntu 14.04 desktop for my client.

I edited  `/etc/fstab` file to mount 2 different servers. When I rebooted it's mounted but not showing mountpath when I run `df -h`

Is there anyone know how to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df -ah
```

`-a` for all, Ref: `man df`

or

```
mount -l
```

Ref: `man mount`